# How do I compare variables following a pattern defined by the user?

Tags: prolog

My predicate needs to compare variables according to the pattern set by the user.

For example :

```
p1([A,A,B,A],[1,1,5,1]).
true

p1([A,A,B,C],[1,1,1,5]).
false

p1([A,B,B,A,C],[2,3,3,2,1]).
true
```

etc.

For now my code only works for 2 variables. I don't know how to make the whole thing recursive.

```
isEqual(A,A).

pattern([A],X):-isEqual(A,X).
pattern([A,A],X):-isEqual(A,A),isEqual(X,[N1,N2]),isEqual(N1,N2).
pattern([A,B],X):-isEqual(X,[N1,N2]),not(isEqual(N1,N2)),A\==B.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This predicate is inherently impure.
What seems to be intended is that all variables in the pattern are different.

```
pattern_instance(Varpattern, Instance) :-
   term_variables(Varpattern, Vs),
   \+ \+ ( Varpattern = Instance, alldifferent(Vs) ).

alldifferent([]).
alldifferent([X|Xs]) :-
   maplist(dif(X), Xs),
   alldifferent(Xs).
```

Comment: What do you mean by inherently impure?

Comment: That this predicate does not and cannot behave like a relation. `X = Y, pattern_instance([X,Y],[1,1])` succeeds, yet its generalization `pattern_instance([X,Y],[1,1])` fails. This is what you intend, but that is not a pure relation.